# Partial solution to linear algebra underdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have m variables $X=\{x_1, \dots, x_m\}$ and I know sums of certain subsets $Y=\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$, where $\forall y_i\in Y$, $y_i$=$∑_{X'\subseteq X, \forall x\in X'}x_i$. Normally $m>n$. Basically, I'm looking for a simple solution of finding $A$ for $AX=Y$ where this linear equation is underdetermined.

Apparently there can exist many solutions. But I am NOT looking for a complete solution that finds all $x_i$ values. Instead I am looking for a partial solution that finds $X'\subseteq X$ from the given $Y$.

Let me give an example. We have:

$X_1+X_2 = 10$

$X_1+X_3+X_4=20$

$X_2+X_3+X_4=20$

In this example we have 4 variables and 3 equations. We can compute that $X_1=X_2=5$. This is an acceptable solution, even though we don't have the value assignment for $X_3$ and $X_4$.

Can you suggest a way that finds a partial solution to linear algebra underdetermined system? I'm looking for a reference to an algorithm which I can understand as a non-mathematician. Even better would be an open source implementation that I can download. Thanks.

Comment: Let me give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Given an equation like $A\vec{v} = \vec{b}$, we usually try the 'best' solution which is the minimum of
$\displaystyle{{1 \over 2}\left(A\vec{v} - \vec{b}\right)^{2}}$. That amounts to solve

$$
A^{\dagger}A\,\vec{v} = A^{\dagger}\,\vec{b}
$$

It can still be undetermined !!!.

Comment: Isn't that (the normal equation) for overdetermined systems?

Comment: Will the "best' solution give a complete solution or a partial solution?

Comment: @ftfish For example, the 'best' of $x = 2$ and $x = 4$ is $3$ which is the minimum of ${1 \over 2}\left[\left(x - 2\right)^{2} + \left(x - 4\right)^{2}\right]$. However,
the procedure yields overdetermined for $x + y = 4$ and $x + y = 1000$.

Comment: @Felix Will be 'best' solution be able to give a partial solution?